# Why sizeof of a structure or union in C need a variable?

Tags: gcc, struct, union, sizeof

The code below could not be compiled(GCC). It said that the person and u_type are undeclared. If I use a variable in sizeof(), it is OK. So why need a variable in sizeof(). [The GNU C Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#The-sizeof-Operator) said that sizeof operator can be used with both type and expression.

Thanks,

```
struct person {
  int age;
  char *name;
};

union u_type {
  int t_int;
  double t_double;
};

int main(void) {
  printf("size of person is %d\n", sizeof(person));
  printf("size of u_type is %d\n", sizeof(u_type));
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in your program called `person` or `u_type`. Sure you have `struct person` and `union u_type` but there are no typedefs to let you just use `person` and `u_type`

Try `sizeof(struct person)`

To answer the questions in the comments:

`struct person { ... };` Gives you a type: `struct person`- where person is a tag. You need to use `struct person` to use the type. In this case `sizeof(struct person)`.

`struct { ... } person;` Gives you a variable called `person` that is a struct (but you can't reuse the type). In this case `sizeof(person)`

The most common use is `typedef struct { ... } Person` which gives you a type Person - much like the first case, but you can use `Person` instead of `struct person`. In this case `sizeof(Person)`

Comment: person and u_type are not types. So what are they?

Comment: `person` is a *tag*.

Comment: I read some tutorials and books that say ```person``` is a tag name, and it is optional when declaring struct. So, when declaring a variable you have to write in full ```struct person var_name```. However, do you know any official document such as language specification that says ```person``` is nothing, and ```struct person``` is  a type?

Comment: @Linh the language standard says `person` is a tag name. It doesn't say `person` is "nothing". A tag name is not a type, but the standard doesn't say that explicitly. It mostly says what things are, not what things aren't.

Answer (score -1):

This is because sizeof operator needs something for which it can tell **size of**.
If it is left empty, it would have nothing to review and generate an answer, but because you have used it in the program by passing no arguments, it will give an error because sizeof empty is kind of vague if you understand.